# JavaScript works only on first page

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have 3 forms (for login, registration and password recovery), and the following code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var
       login = {
            user: 'afy-usr-log',
            pass: 'afy-pas-log'
       },

       register = {
            user: 'afy-usr-reg',
            pass: 'afy-pas-reg',
            mail: 'afy-eml-reg'
       },

       forget = {
            user: 'afy-usr-psf',
            captcha: 'afy-cpt-psf'
       },

       names = {
            login: 'afy-usrlog',
            register: 'afy-usrreg',
            forget: 'afy-usrpsf'
       };


    document.querySelector('body').onkeyup = function() {
        /* login */
        if(document.getElementById(login['user']).value != '' && document.getElementById(login['pass']).value != '') {
            document.getElementsByName(names['login'])[0].removeAttribute('disabled');
        }
        else {
            document.getElementsByName(names['login'])[0].setAttribute('disabled', '');
        }

        /* register */
        if(document.getElementById(register['user']).value != '' && document.getElementById(register['pass']).value != '' && document.getElementById(register['mail']).value != '') {
            document.getElementsByName(names['register'])[0].removeAttribute('disabled');
        }
        else {
            document.getElementsByName(names['register'])[0].setAttribute('disabled', '');
        }

        /* forget password */
        if(document.getElementById(forget['user']).value != '' && document.getElementById(forget['captcha']).value != '') {
            document.getElementsByName(names['forget'])[0].removeAttribute('disabled');
        }
        else {
            document.getElementsByName(names['forget'])[0].setAttribute('disabled', '');
        }
    }
});
```

This code works perfectly on my main page, `index.php`, which contains only register form and login form, but if I add `?v=1` (which contains only password recovery form) to the address line, the script won't work anymore. (actually, it can work, if I replace the last if/else with the first one, but then the others won't work - the 1st and the 2nd if/else).

How can I solve this?

Comment: question is not clear still

Comment: @VasimVanzara How can I make it work on any other page (and not only on `index.php`) ?

Comment: are you working with core php?

Comment: Based on this information it's impossible to tell. First check that the script is actually included in the page when it doesn't work (right click -> view source). Then open the browser's JavaScript console and see what error messages are printed there.

Comment: @VasimVanzara yes but the problem is with JS - I mean, the javascript file not working on `?v=1` or any other page (`page1.php` etc)

Comment: create a file and include it your header part

Comment: the other pages contain same html elements with same IDs and name?

Comment: @VasimVanzara it's included

Comment: @Juhana there is no error

Comment: did you debug with break point?

Comment: @LeonardLepadatu It can work only if the login form is included

Comment: I know, that was why I ask the question...  Please try:  document.addEventListener('load',  ....

Comment: @Leonard Lepadatu  `document.addEventListener('load', function(){...});` not working at all

Comment: Sorry, use window.addEventListner('load',  ....

Comment: @Leonard Lepadatu `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null` error

Comment: OK, this is good! So you don't have this element in you second/third page! So one solution is spiting this script in three scripts, one for every page. The other solution is to check if the element is in your page: var myElem = document.getElementById('myElementId');
if (myElem !== null) { // your code here };  For every element!

Comment: @LeonardLepadatu WOW!!!! Thank You!!! please, add this as an answer so I can check your answer as helpful (accept the answer). it works!

Comment: U r welcome, my friend! Please note that using jQuery you "life" will be more easy ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your code like this:

```
document.querySelector('body').onkeyup = function() {
        /* login */
        if(
        (null !== document.getElementById(login['user']) &&                
         '' !== document.getElementById(login['user']).value) && 
        (null !== document.getElementById(login['pass']) &&  
         '' !== document.getElementById(login['pass']).value) {
            document.getElementsByName(names['login'])[0].removeAttribute('disabled');
        }
        else ...
```

Comment: Here controls are not avaible at load event? appriciate with +1

Answer (score 0):

> which contains only password recovery form

If it only contains that form, then the code is going to hit the first `getElementById` statement, get `null` back from it, and then try to read the `value` of `null`.

That will throw an exception, which should have shown in in the Console of your browser's Developer Tools. (NB: It is very nearly vital that you look in the Console and quote error messages when asking questions about you code, along similar lines you should provide a [MCVE] which would include enough HTML to reproduce the problem).

Since you are getting an exception, the JS will abort.

You need to get the return value from `getElementById`, and then **check that it is a true value** (with an `if`) before trying to use it.

Answer (score 0):

First check you are reach to code simple alert.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var
       login = {
            user: 'afy-usr-log',
            pass: 'afy-pas-log'
       },

       register = {
            user: 'afy-usr-reg',
            pass: 'afy-pas-reg',
            mail: 'afy-eml-reg'
       },

       forget = {
            user: 'afy-usr-psf',
            captcha: 'afy-cpt-psf'
       },

       names = {
            login: 'afy-usrlog',
            register: 'afy-usrreg',
            forget: 'afy-usrpsf'
       };


    document.querySelector('body').onkeyup = function() {
          //alert("You are in body");
    console.log(document.getElementsByName(names));


       }
});
```

Comment: If I was the one who did the downvote, I probably was telling why. anyway, I tried with alert, and it worked

Comment: Please check do you get name object?

Comment: It means you haven't dom objects control here